# Problema al realizar insercion. Inserta tres veces el mismo registro!

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy insertando datos en una tabla llamada pagos, la tabla almacena pagos que ha hecho un estudiante, el problema surge que cuando se inscribe un estudiante por primera vez para despues procesarle el primer pago en la tabla pagos se guardan dos filas con todos los campos vacios y ya en la 3era fila es que guarda los datos bien. pero eso solo pasa cuando es el primer pago de un estudiante nuevo, si le vuelvo a procesar otro pago a ese mismo estudiante si guarda los datos bien. En el formulario en que mando los datos, algunos inputs estan rellenos con una consulta. Dejare la funcion en donde hago la insercion.

```
public function pago_cuota($id,$f_pay,$concepto,$monto,$forma,$bco,$refer)
  {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root', '' , 'academia');

    $estatus = "PAGADA";
    $fecha_new = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$f_pay + 1 month"));

    $query = "INSERT INTO pagos(id_student,concepto,monto,forma_pago,banco,n_referencia,fecha_pago,estatus)
    VALUES('$id','$concepto','$monto','$forma','$bco','$refer', '$fecha_new','$estatus')";
    $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
  }
```

Comment: *se guardan dos filas con todos los campos vacios y ya en la 3era fila es que guarda los datos bien. * ¿Podrías explicarlo de otra manera? ¿Por qué creas 3 registros al inscribir un estudiante?

Comment: No comentas nada del diseño de tu base de datos. ¿Por qué haces inserción de estudiantes y pagos al mismo tiempo? ¿Acaso no tienes una tabla `estudiantes` y otra `pagos` enlazadas a través de llaves foráneas?  En cuanto a darte una solución efectiva, sería bueno que mostrases el código en el cual insertas el estudiante y haces los pagos. No entiendo el que _algunos inputs están rellenos con una consulta_ ¿no habrá otra forma mejor de hacer eso? Y por último, tus consultas son vulnerables a la Inyección SQL. Se recomienda usar consultas preparadas en estos casos.

Comment: Matias cuando proceso el primer pago de un nuevo estudiante, en mi tabla pagos se llenan 3 filas, las dos primeras vacias y la 3 si con los datos que he mandado en el formulario. Ejemplo de como queda mi tabla: id 1: vacias todos los campos, id 2: vacios todos los campos, id 3: llenos todos los campos con la informacion correcta. Pero como mencione eso solo pasa cuando es un nuevo estudiante y es su primer pago, en el segundo pago no guarda filas vacias.

Comment: Cedano no hago insercion de estudiantes y pagos al mismo tiempo, ese id_student es el id del estudiante que realiza ese pago, ese id lo traigo de un input hidden. tengo una tabla estudiantes y pagos separadas y relacionadas entre si, el codigo que hago los pagos es la funcion que coloque arriba, los inputs rellenos con una consulta es porque tengo q rellenar automaticamente el concepto y el monto de ese pago, que esos datos me los traigo de otra tabla que es donde estan los montos de cada cuota y que cuota es. cambiare a consultas preparadas, pero estoy probando primero asi

Comment: function inscribir($names,$ced,$fnac,$direc,$tlfm,$tlfl,$curso,$f_pago,$enc){
    $mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost','root','','academia');
    $query = "INSERT INTO students(id_curso,names,ced,f_nacimiento,address,phone_m,phone_loc,encuesta)
 VALUES('$curso','$fecha','$names','$ced','$fnac','$direc','$tlfm','$tlfl','$enc','$pay')";

    $insert = $mysqli->query($query);
    $val = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pagos(id_student,fecha_pago)VALUES('$val','$f_pago')";
    $insert2 = $mysqli->query($sql);
  }

Comment: _el problema surge que cuando se inscribe un estudiante por primera vez para despues procesarle el primer pago en la tabla pagos se guardan dos filas con todos los campos vacios y ya en la 3era fila es que guarda los datos bien_ al leer esto interpreto que guardas estudiantes y pagos al mismo tiempo. En cuanto a tener consultas en inputs hidden no le veo el sentido. Cuando necesita datos precargados puedes llenar `selects` con esos datos como ocurre por ejemplo con formularios en los que seleccionas países,  ciudades u otros datos que vienen precargados.

Comment: no cedano, no guardo estudiantes y pagos al mismo tiempo. cuando se inscribe un estudiante se hace en la tabla estudiantes nada mas, despues cuando ya esta inscrito es que yo procedo a buscarlo y a procesarle el primer pago. y lo del hidden se que no deberia tenerlo. pero cuando voy a guardar ese pago de ese estudiante no me guarda el id de ese estudiante, y con el hidden si lo hace. arriba coloque la funcion de inscribir estudiante

Comment: Creo que deberías sentarte a reflexionar tu aplicación, porque de lo contrario te vas a líar... Si estamos hablando de un **formulario de pagos**, tu puedes tener precargado en dicho formulario un combobox o select con todos los estudiantes. Seleccionas el estudiante que va a efectuar el pago. Cuando seleccionas un estudiante deberías tener algo así como un tabla o radio buttons que muestren el estado crediticio del estudiante, que te muestren lo que debe y te permitan seleccionar alguno para efectuar un pago. Si son miles de estudiantes en vez de un select deberías tener un campo para buscar.

Comment: La cuestión es que, **al seleccionar cualquier estudiante** deberías desplegar una acción que busque en la base de datos y te muestre en pantalla el estado actual de dicho estudiante. Es decir, una pantalla con **todo** el plan de pagos de ese estudiante. Así sabrás si ese estudiante debe agosto, si no paga des ¡diciembre!, si tiene todo pago. Los meses pagados debería aparecer desactivados por ejemplo, o en color verde... y los no pagados en rojo, con un radio al lado que podrás activar en caso de que quiera pagar ese mes... dar la posibilidad de hacer varios pagos, etc.

Comment: Te explico, tengo una tabla con estudiantes inscritos la cual tiene su buscador por nombre. ahora yo clickeo sobre el estudiante y me aparece un div con un form el cual tiene su fecha de pago, la cuota que va a pagar que si la traigo en un select y el monto de la cuota que va a pagar, esos dos datos me los traigo de una consulta que hago. funciona asi cuando clickeo el nombre del estudiante llama a la funcion ver datos, la cual se compone por la consulta que menciono, y los datos de esa consulta los muestro en un select y en un input. pienso que mi problema esta en el input hidden que mencione

Comment: cedano te entiendo lo del select con los estudiantes. pero imaginate es una cantidad n de estudiantes, no seria lo mejor hacerlo con un select. por eso lo tengo en una tabla con un buscador por nombre. y cuando clickeo sobre el estudiante mando el id de ese estudiante a la consulta que te mencione.

Comment: Yo hablo de suposiciones, comenté que si son muchos estudiantes puedes tener un campo de búsqueda... o puedes tener filtros por cursos también, eso es lo de menos. Lo que no termino de entender es lo del input hidden ni que utilidad tendría sin planteas la solución como he comentado más arriba. Además me parece que no es una buena solución dar la posibilidad de un solo pago. Como te decía, al seleccionar un estudiante deberías mostrar en un div **todo** lo que debe y si es útil también todo lo que ha pagado.  Imagina que quiere pagar 2 meses o 3 ese mismo día.

Comment: Creeme que tampoco me gusta lo de un solo pago pero asi me lo estan pidiendo porque son pagos mensuales, y ellos por ejemplo si van a pagar 3 meses cargan pago por pago. te explico lo del hidden sabes que al clickear el estudiante se manda ese id el cual lo recibo antes de la sentencia con GET. pero entonces cuando voy a hacer ese pago sin ese hidden no me guarda el id del estudiante en la tabla pagos. y probe a colocar ese input y funciona pero mal. no se de que manera lo pueda hacer. no soy experto en PHP por eso el enredo disculpa

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

---

Conexión:

```
<?php

    $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","colegio"); //servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
?>
```

---

Formulario que agrega:

```
//  <body
<form method="post" action="" >
   <input name="cod">
   <input name="nom">
   <input name="apelli">
   <input name="ed">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insertar">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        require("insertar.php");
    }
?>

// /body
```

---

Ingresar los datos con la función:

```
<?php
$codd=$_POST['cod'];
$apelll=$_POST['nom'];
$nomm= $_POST['apelli'];
$edd=$_POST['ed'];

require("conexion.php");
if($codd>0){

    require("conexion.php");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO alumnos (id, nombre, apellidos, edad) 
            VALUES ('".$codd."','".$apelll."','".$nomm."','".$edd."');";

    $query_new_user_insert = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    echo 'Se ha registrado con exito';
    echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Usuario registrado con éxito");</script> ';


}else{
    echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("deben ingresar un codigo");</script> ';
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, efectivamente llamo a mi funcion con isset. cuando haya POST de pagar. pero creo que el problema no esta alli, sabes que en mi formulario relleno algunos inputs con datos de una consulta que muestro a traves de un id que recibo, pero en el form tengo un input hidden y en su value tengo el id que estoy recibiendo, lo hice asi porque sin ese hidden no me funcionada, el id lo recibo antes de la sentencia con GET. No se si por eso sea el error en la insercion.